# Ubuntu 10.04 Virtual Appliance for KVM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, virtual-appliances

I have an Ubuntu 10.04.3 guest running on VMWare ESXi 5.0. I want to create a virtual appliance of this guest that can be deployed on a KVM host.

Can anyone please provide me some suitable pointers and reference links that can be followed ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the appliance to do? Have you tried any research of your own? If you are asking for best practices you need to be more specific.

Comment: The Ubuntu VM has a running Puppet Master, Subversion, Puppet-Dashboard etc. Since all the packages are already installed with their respective dependencies, I would like to create a virtual appliance of this setup and distribute among people.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked for closure, the question is quite valid IMO

Answer (score 1):

First, use `virt-v2v` to convert the guest to libvirt and KVM format. Then package the guest image and VM definitions, and you're good to go.